# A few value convert to CSV Mulesoft

Tags: csv, mule, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv quoteValues=true, separator=";", header=true
---
[
    {
        Aaa: payload.problem.Aaa[0],
        Bbb: payload.problem.Bbb[0]
}
]
```

And this write it to CSV like this:

```
Aaa;Bbb
1234; Test1
```

But this payload looks like this:

```
 "problem": {
        "Aaa": [
            "1234",
            "1567",
            "105"
        ],
        "Bbb": [
            "Test1",
            "Test2",
            "Test3"
        ]
}
```

And I would like to write all 3 value or more depends from my request to my CSV. But now I can do it only if I specify which element from the array (example payload.issues.Aaa[0]). Because under my key Aaa I don't know exactly how many value I will get to response.

Answer (score 2):

This solution assumes that the data for the first column has the same number of rows as all the others.

First I capture the names of columns from the key names in payload.problem, using the function namesOf(), and store the array of names in the variable column.

Then I map over the first 'column' to get the index of each row. Using that index I iterate over each column name obtaining the value for that column at that index, and transforming it into a key-value (column name, value of that column for the row). Finally I use reduce() to concatenate all the key-values from the same row into a single object, which represents the row as DataWeave expects to transform to CSV. If you change the output type to JSON you will see the structure more clearly.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/csv quoteValues=true, separator=";", header=true
var columns=namesOf(payload.problem)
---
payload.problem[columns[0]] map ((item, index) -> (
    columns map ($): payload.problem[$][index]) 
        reduce ($$++$) 
)
```

Output:

```csv
Aaa;Bbb
"1234";"Test1"
"1567";"Test2"
"105";"Test3"
```

If the columns are not of the same size you can use this alternative that will find first a column with the maximum length and use it as the first iteration:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/csv quoteValues=true, separator=";", header=true
import firstWith from dw::core::Arrays
var columns=namesOf(payload.problem)
var maxColumnSize=max(columns map sizeOf(payload.problem[$]))
var maxColumnName=columns firstWith (sizeOf(payload.problem[$]) == maxColumnSize)
---
payload.problem[maxColumnName] 
    map ((item, index) -> (
        columns map ($): payload.problem[$][index]) 
            reduce ($$++$) 
    )
```

Comment: Could you explain how it's working? Why you use reduce at the end ?

Comment: I have this error trying this "Cannot coerce Array { class: java.util.ArrayList } to String". I think it's not always that column Aaa and Bbb have the same rows.

Comment: I added a detailed explanation. About the error, I tested it with the input from the question. If you have different inputs you should add more cases to the question, and/or clarify the kinds of inputs. We can only assume so much with the information we receive.

Comment: I added an alternative that will work with uneven sized columns.